Concentration Inequality for the bounded random variables
This is a problem I encountered while studying  High-Dimensional Statistics, it is about the Concentration inequality for the bounded random variables
The question is: Consider a sequence of independent random variables $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ that satisfy
$0\leq X_k\leq b$ for each $k$. Let $Z=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Show that
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}[Z\geq (1+t)\mathbb{E}[Z]] &\leq \left(\frac{e^t}{(1+t)^{(1+t)}}\right)^{\mathbb{E}[Z]/b} \ \text{for}\ t>0,\\
    \mathbb{P}[Z\leq (1-t)\mathbb{E}[Z]] &\leq \left(\frac{e^t}{(1-t)^{(1-t)}}\right)^{\mathbb{E}[Z]/b} \ \text{for}\ t\in (0,1).
\end{align*}
I tried to use Hoeffding's inequality to prove it. Since $0\leq X_k\leq b$ for each $k$, so $Z$ is $\frac{nb^2}{4}$-sub-Gaussian. By the Hoeffding's inequality, $\mathbb{P}[≥(1+)[]]\leq \exp(-\frac{2(1+t)^2 \mathbb{E}[Z]^2)}{nb^2})$.
The right-hand side of the inequality, however, is independent of , and the term $(1+t)^{1+t}$ appears, I don't know how to obtain this result.

What inequalities do you know? Like, Azuma's inequality? Hoeffding's inequality? Chernoff? I don't think the inequality you have used (bounded case concentration) is good enough.

I'm sorry I didn't make it clear which inequalities I know. In fact, I have tried to use Markov's inequality, Hoeffding's inequality, and inequalities about bounded random variables. However, I am not quite sure about the derivation of the term  $(1+t)^{1+t}$. About the Chernoff inequality, since the problem did not specify that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed, I did not consider using it.

The answer here is kind of all over the place, but see what you can make of it? It does have the same question but I have to see if that's enough for you to get the answer.

Here are some attempts I made: since $0\leq X_k\leq b, Z=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$, so $Z$ is $\frac{nb^2}{4}$-sub-Gaussian. By the Hoeffding's inequality, $\mathbb{P}[Z\geq (1+t)\mathbb{E}[Z]]\leq \exp (-\frac{2(1+t)^2\mathbb{E}[Z]^2}{nb^2})$.But I'm a bit lost on what to do next.

Welcome to MSE @Joker, please  consider adding your attempts in the body of the question so that it avoids getting closed for lack of context (although, in my opinion, the question doesn't deserve to get closed as-is)

Thank you! I've changed it.

Joker, please have a look in the edit and the complete solution of questions 1 and 2.

Without loss of generality we take $b=1.$ Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ independent random variables  valued in $[0,1]$
Consider $Z=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ , $m=E(Z)$ and $a>1.$ We show  that
$$\Pr(Z>am)\leq \left (\frac{e^{a-1}}{a^a}\right)^m\ \ (*).$$
To prove it, for fixed $x\in[0,1]$ and $s>0$ we observe   $f_x(s)=(1-x)+xe^s-e^{sx}\geq 0.$ This comes from the fact that $f_x(0)=0$ and $f_x'(s)=x(e^s-e^{-sx})>0.$ As a consequence if $m_i=E(X_i)$ we have for $s>0$
$$E(e^{sX_i})\leq E(1-X_i+X_i e^s)=1+m_i(e^s-1))\leq \exp (m_i(e^s-1)).$$
The Markov inequality says that for all $s$
$$\Pr(Z>am)=\Pr(e^{sZ}>e^{ams})\leq e^{-ams}E(e^{sZ})\leq \prod_{i=1}^n\exp[ -am_i s+m_i(e^s-1))]$$
choosing $s=\log a$ gives (*).
For the second part I don't understand it since it suggests a majorization of a probability by a number >1.

Thank you very much for your answer, but may I ask how you came up with setting $f_x(s) = (1-x)+x e^s -e^{sx}$?

Just after many dead ends,
